# Leaflet.Draw edit and delete button not working

Tags: javascript, django, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I'm using Leaflet Draw to let users draw a polyline in a map in order to measure sections. First step is to use Leaflet.Draw to let users draw the line. Leaflet.Draw includes a delete and edit button. These buttons are, however not working.

I've (re)used working code from other projects to create the draw control and pass it a FeatureGroup and editable layers.

```
// My draw Toolbar
var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup()
map.addLayer(drawnItems)
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
  draw:{polygon: false,
        marker: false,
        circlemarker: false,
        rectangle: false,
        circle: false,
    },
  edit: {
    featureGroup: drawnItems
  }
});

map.addControl(drawControl);
map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (e) {
   var layer = e.layer;
   map.addLayer(layer);
});
```

Seems like I'm linking the feature group correctly, but for some reason the delete and edit are not working :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're adding the drawn items to `map` but [they should be added to the layer pointed by `edit.featureGroup` if you want to edit them](https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html#editpolyoptions), i.e `drawnItems`:

```
map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (e) {
    var layer = e.layer;
    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
});
```

Here's a demo https://jsfiddle.net/4g5u071r/